# PyQt icons missing?

Tags: python, pyqt

I am new to PyQt and I am learning to make GUIs based on online tutorials I found. One of the examples in the tutorials uses an icon, here is the code from the tutorial:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):               

        exitAct = QAction(QIcon('exit24.png'), 'Exit', self)
        exitAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAct.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Exit')
        self.toolbar.addAction(exitAct)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Toolbar')    
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The output according to the tutorial should be

[image]
But for me it's this

[image]
As I said, I just started with PyQt and I just installed PyQt through pip

```
pip install PyQt5
```

I'm using Python3.6 and PyQt5. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you add your icon to the resources folder for the application?

Comment: I'm not sure where to get the icons from, I thought they would come with the PyQt5 installation to be honest

Comment: Where is the .png? Is it next to your .py?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, PyQt5 does come with a list of default icons. You can find them here:
[List of PyQt Icons](https://joekuan.wordpress.com/2015/09/23/list-of-qt-icons/)

However, it seems the "exit" icon from the tutorial you refrenced used a local icon downloaded on their computer. You need to download the same icon and name it 'exit24.png' next to your python file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simply follow these steps from here:
[How to set icon to a window in PyQt5 ?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-set-icon-to-a-window-in-pyqt5/)

Also you can use the `QT Designer` which can be downloaded from here:
[Qt Designer Download](https://build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download) and add the icon basically from there.

Alternatively, you can use the `Pyinstaller` to add icon on the GUI executable. You can follow the steps: [Pyinstaller Usage](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html)